# How to select interface for http_client in cpprest

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I'm using cpprest sdk for my http client application.
Workstation running this application has 2 network interfaces/adapters: eth0 and eth1.
How can I specify in http_client code which interface shall be used to send http request and receive response?

Comment: It could be useful using custom header [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718955/sending-a-http-post-request-for-updating-file-contents-using-c-rest-sdk-casabl)